# How do I create a Finder alias within an application?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, finder

What is the code necessary to create a Finder alias from a Cocoa application?
Are there any differences for that code between OS X 10.5, 10.6, and 10.7?

Comment: One way to do it is to embed some AppleScript into your app, this has functions to do that. Refer to docs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since OS X 10.6 you can use `NSUrl`'s `writeBookmarkData:toURL:options:error:` method

From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURL/writeBookmarkData:toURL:options:error:):

> Creates an alias file on disk at a specified location with specified
>   bookmark data.

Sample code:

```
NSURL *originalUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/this/is/your/path"];
NSURL *aliasUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/your/alias/path"];
NSData *bookmarkData = [originalUrl bookmarkDataWithOptions: NSURLBookmarkCreationSuitableForBookmarkFile includingResourceValuesForKeys:nil relativeToURL:nil error:NULL];

if(bookmarkData != nil) {
    BOOL success = [NSURL writeBookmarkData:bookmarkData toURL:aliasUrl options:NSURLBookmarkCreationSuitableForBookmarkFile error:NULL];
    if(NO == success) {
        //error
    }
}
```

However, aliases created in that way are not backwards-compatible to earlier OS X versions (pre 10.6)

Comment: Since I was interested for at least OS X 10.6, this is the answer I was looking for. There is nothing wrong with Carbon code in a Cocoa application, but I prefer using Cocoa, when possible.

Comment: Is this the same thing that happens when I right click and say "Make Alias" like in this screenshot -  http://i.imgur.com/JEHZLcl.png ?

Comment: @kiamlaluno and codingFrined, is there a typo in this snippet on line 3? It says `NSData *bookmarkData = [url ` but what is `url`? Is `url` supposed to be `originalURL`?

Comment: @Noitidart yes, that's a typo. I fixed it. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Thanks @codingFriend1 :)

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [How to Create an Alias Programmatically](http://www.danandcheryl.com/tag/alias).

```
- (void)makeAliasToFolder:(NSString *)destFolder inFolder:(NSString *)parentFolder withName:(NSString *)name
{
    // Create a resource file for the alias.
    FSRef parentRef;
    CFURLGetFSRef((CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:parentFolder], &parentRef);
    HFSUniStr255 aliasName;
    FSGetHFSUniStrFromString((CFStringRef)name, &aliasName);
    FSRef aliasRef;
    FSCreateResFile(&parentRef, aliasName.length, aliasName.unicode, 0, NULL, &aliasRef, NULL);

    // Construct alias data to write to resource fork.
    FSRef targetRef;
    CFURLGetFSRef((CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:destFolder], &targetRef);
    AliasHandle aliasHandle = NULL;
    FSNewAlias(NULL, &targetRef, &aliasHandle);

    // Add the alias data to the resource fork and close it.
    ResFileRefNum fileReference = FSOpenResFile(&aliasRef, fsRdWrPerm);
    UseResFile(fileReference);
    AddResource((Handle)aliasHandle, 'alis', 0, NULL);
    CloseResFile(fileReference);

    // Update finder info.
    FSCatalogInfo catalogInfo;
    FSGetCatalogInfo(&aliasRef, kFSCatInfoFinderInfo, &catalogInfo, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    FileInfo *theFileInfo = (FileInfo*)(&catalogInfo.finderInfo);
    theFileInfo->finderFlags |= kIsAlias; // Set the alias bit.
    theFileInfo->finderFlags &= ~kHasBeenInited; // Clear the inited bit to tell Finder to recheck the file.
    theFileInfo->fileType = kContainerFolderAliasType;
    FSSetCatalogInfo(&aliasRef, kFSCatInfoFinderInfo, &catalogInfo);
}
```

You can also use applescript

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to make alias file to POSIX file "/Applications/myapp.app" at POSIX file "/Applications/"'
```

Comment: You can also check out the [BDAlias library](https://github.com/rentzsch/bdalias).

Comment: It should be noted that this solution is the outdated (deprecated) way. Use this only if you must, and use `writeBookmarkData` if you can. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37309635/ for learning how to create a bookmark file from an Alias record.

Answer (score 1):

Creates an alias file on disk at a specified location with specified bookmark data using Swift3.

Sample Code :

```
let url = URL(string: "originalURL")
let aliasUrl = URL(string: "aliasURL")
do{
      let data = try url.bookmarkData(options: .suitableForBookmarkFile, includingResourceValuesForKeys: nil, relativeTo: nil)
            try URL.writeBookmarkData(data, to: aliasUrl)
  }catch{}
```

Answer (score -1):

You want `-[NSFileManager linkItemAtPath:toPath:error:]`. AFIK, it and its related methods are the preferred means across all versions.

Comment: Isn't an alias different from a link? I think I read that a Finder alias as some features that are not present in a link, which would make it preferable to links.

Comment: Hard links (as the one created with the reported function) cannot be created on a volume that is different from the source one. A Finder alias in a mix between a soft link and a hard link, which means that a Finder alias would be valid even when the file is moved, and it is possible to set an alias on a different volume than the source volume.

Comment: A hard link is *nothing* like an alias. Hard-linking a file puts it in two places or under two different names (or both) at once. It does not create a new file of either a special type (symbolic link) or with special contents (alias or bookmark).

Comment: That is why I asked about Finder aliases.