# Create Desktop shortcut on MAC OS X ( like .desktop in linux )

Tags: c++, linux, macos

How to create a desktop shortcut in MAC OSX using C++ only.

in linux i can do by using .desktop file

```
[Desktop Entry]  
Version=1.0  
Name=Eclipse  
Exec=/usr/local/bin/eclipse
```

Comment: Desktop shortcuts aren't really a thing on Mac OS X... I never make shortcuts on the desktop. Application shortcuts either go in the dock (or Launchpad), and there's the folder stacks for Documents and Downloads already.

Comment: But, if you really wanted to make a shortcut on the desktop, you'd want to make an *alias*.

Comment: The close vote is not correct, the OP is asking about how to do it with C++, which makes it on-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: Whoever is voting to close is not reading the question!

Comment: I have provided the code to create an alias in OS X 10.8 or newer. If you need to target 10.7 or earlier, you can use [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11095831/10320).

Answer (score 1):

As has been mentioned, by @dreamlax, it's an alias that you would be creating; at least, this is what the UI provides when you right-click on an item: -

[image]

If you use the terminal and create a symbolic link to an item on the desktop, you'll see that it creates a **similar** 'alias'. So what you could do is create a symbolic link to the source item with a call to the [ln function](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ln.1.html), which may be the same as the [symlink](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man7/symlink.7.html) function call.

Note that the alias created with the UI is not exactly the same as that created by ln, as you can see when linking to a pkg (installer) file. if you use the '[file](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/file.1.html)' command on the two. Using ln, the created link is identified as "xar archive - version 1", whereas the UI alias creates a file which is "alias: data".

However, as far as functionality goes, both should work as a way of placing a link on the desktop to an item in another location.

Finally, take note of [this distinction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_(Mac_OS)) between the POSIX ln and alias before deciding if ln is suitable for your situation: -

> [alias] is similar to the Unix symbolic link, but with the distinction of working even if the target file moves to another location on the same disk

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make an alias, have a look at the [Alias Manager reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/Alias_Manager/Reference/reference.html), or if you are targeting 10.8 or later, you can use [`CFURLCreateBookmarkData`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFURLRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFURLCreateBookmarkData) instead.

#### Edit

In fact, you may even be able to just use the POSIX [`symlink`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/symlink.html) to create a shortcut. Try that first and if that suffices, don't bother with the more complicated Alias Manager or `CFURLCreateBookmarkData`.

#### Edit 2

Here is the C code required to create a bookmark (you'll need to specify `-framework CoreFoundation` to the command line flags for the compiler if you are compiling from the command line, or otherwise add the CoreFoundation framework to your project in Xcode).

```
CFErrorRef error = NULL;
CFURLRef aliasFile = CFURLCreateWithString(NULL, CFSTR("file:///Users/msl/Desktop/Terminal%20Alias"), NULL);
CFURLRef targetFile = CFURLCreateWithString(NULL, CFSTR("file:///Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app"), NULL);
CFDataRef bookmark = CFURLCreateBookmarkData(NULL, targetFile, kCFURLBookmarkCreationSuitableForBookmarkFile, NULL, NULL, &error);

if (bookmark == NULL)
{
    // something went wrong, check what "error" variable says
}

Boolean success = CFURLWriteBookmarkDataToFile(bookmark, aliasFile, kCFURLBookmarkCreationSuitableForBookmarkFile, &error);
if (!success)
{
    // something went wrong, check what "error" variable says
}

// make sure to clean up
if (bookmark) CFRelease(bookmark);
if (aliasFile) CFRelease(aliasFile);
if (targetFile) CFRelease(targetFile);
```

Comment: i am working on 10.9 so i am going to try with CFURLCreateBookmarkData

Comment: I don't see what `CFURLCreateBookmarkData` has anything to do with this?

Comment: well i may have to pass an argument to application, so symlink may not be a good option

Comment: @trojanfoe: [here's the Objective-C equivalent for creating a bookmark](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928139/how-do-i-create-a-finder-alias-within-an-application). Basically you create the bookmark data with `CFURLCreateBookmarkData`, which contains the the target to link to, and then write the bookmark data to a file using [`CFURLWriteBookmarkDataToFile`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFURLRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001206-CH1g-SW21) to create the actual alias.

Comment: OK I see; I have only encountered this method WRT saving security-scoped bookmarks within a sandboxed app.

Answer (score -1):

Hold Shift key, and drag application to target location. e.g: Desktop.

Comment: This is not answering the question.